# Get results from AppleScript with Java on OSX

Tags: java, macos, applescript, itunes

I'm looking for a sophisticated way to get data from Applescript using a Java application.

Simple example :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Throwable {
    String script = "tell application \"iTunes\"\n" +
            "\treturn current track\n" +
            "end tell";

    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");
    Object res = engine.eval(script);
    System.out.println(res);
    System.out.println(res.getClass());
}
```

This returns

```
<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'obj '{ 'form':'ID  ', 'want':'cFlT', 'seld':162556, 'from':'obj '{ 'form':'ID  ', 'want':'cUsP', 'seld':162443, 'from':'obj '{ 'form':'ID  ', 'want':'cSrc', 'seld':65, 'from':null() } } }>
```

class java.lang.String

I may interpret or parse this string, but does a more elaborate way exist, like returning JSON?